# newb just reading from a book and copying lessons, stuck on lesson one :(

Tags: html, button

just got a book from the library and was trying to learn a bit about simple html coding and first lesson of writing a simple program doesn't do what it is supposed to. no idea whats as it is copied exactly as the book shows. the button does not display its answer and I already found one typo on the first lesson so any help is appreciated. also not sure if this is displaying the code only let me know if it isn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            /* This is the function that gets
            called when the user clicks the
            button on the main page */

            function displayAnswer()
            {
                document.write(“Just 24 1-hour lessons!”);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>My First Program</h1>
        <p id=“demo”>How long will it take for me to learn to program? </p>

        <button type=“button” onclick=“displayAnswer()”>How many hours?</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Press f12 and check is there any error present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you either copied your code from an online book or you wrote it in something like Microsoft word.  You need to write code in a straight text editor like textpad or note pad if you don't have actual development environment. 
Your editor replaced all of the double quotes with the wrong kind.

there is way more information than you need but this site has pitures  that show the different types of quotes http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

You want to use the double quotes that go straight up and down, not ones that lean.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>

                /* This is the function that gets
                called when the user clicks the
                button on the main page */

                function displayAnswer()
                {
                    document.write("Just 24 1-hour lessons!");
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>My First Program</h1>
        <p id="demo">How long will it take for me to learn to program? </p>

        <button type="button" onclick="displayAnswer()">How many hours?</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You using the wrong character for quotes
it needs to be "

The code works like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

/* This is the function that gets
called when the user clicks the
button on the main page */

function displayAnswer()
{
document.write("Just 24 1-hour lessons!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Program</h1>
<p id="demo">How long will it take for me to learn to program? </p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayAnswer()">How many hours?</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wrote it in text edit that came with my iMac, changed the preferences of the format to plain text (not rich text) and checked the box the "display html files as html code instead of formatted text" but I don't see another set of quotes that are straight up and down instead of leaning on my keyboard, is there some other preference I have to change for that?

Comment: EDIT : ah never mind the power of google has helped me.  I just used text edit because it came with my Mac but would download something else if you have any suggestions (free would be good for now not opposed to paying a little bit either if its going to work better than text edit)

Comment: and it works now! yay thank you, nice to know there are resources like this out there for newbies trying to learn from a book instead of a class and there no teacher to ask.